# display navbar by default if page cannot scroll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, navbar

I have a navbar in a web page I am working on. I added some jquery code to display the navbar when the user scrolls down. The problem with this is there are a few pages where the entire height of the page is so small that the user will not be able to scroll down. In this scenario, the navbar is never displayed as there is no possibility of scrolling.

How do I change my code so that, if there is no possibility of scrolling then the navbar is displayed by default?

Here is my jquery code to the display the navbar when the user scrolls

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onscroll = function() {
      scrollFunction()
    };

    function scrollFunction() {
      if (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80) {
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-100px";
      }
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best way to go about this would be to compare the document height with the window height to know if the document is within the browser's window height. So I would write something like this:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement;

    var documentHeight = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
                       html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );

    if (documentHeight <= window.innerHeight) {
       document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
    } else {
      window.onscroll = function() {
        scrollFunction()
      };

      function scrollFunction() {
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80) {
          document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
        } else {
          document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-100px";
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
```

The document height calculation is a little bit messy in vanilla JS, you could probably put that inside a function to make it cleaner if you want.